# How to remove a notification panel in android

Tags: android

How to make simple android app,that can be disable all thing of notification panel

```
 View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide the status bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
// Remember that you should never show the action bar if the
// status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

Comment: What is your question ? What is the problem ?

Comment: My question is i want to disable notification panel forever